# How do I implement a parser that respects order of operations in a stack-based AST?

Tags: parsing, recursion, rust, stack, operator-precedence

I have a parser that parses the following arithmetic
`1 + 2 * 2`
Into the following stack AST: `Const(1) Const(2) Add Const(2) Mul`.
I need it to parse into this stack AST `Const(2) Const(2) Mul Const(1) Add`

I would also need to parse `2 * 2 + 1 / 3` correctly as `Const(2) Const(2) Mul Const(1) Const(3) Div Add` and any other combination.

My algorithm currently looks something like this (rust pseudocode):

```rs
let mut add_next = None;
while let Some(token) = tokens.next() { // Iterate over tokens
   match_token(token, &mut add_next);
}
```

```rs
fn match_token(token: Token, &mut add_next: Ops) {
   let original_add_next = add_next.clone();
   match token {
     Token::Const(x) => push_ops(Ops::Const(x)),
     Token::Add => add_next = Some(Ops::Add),
     Token::Mul => add_next = Some(Ops::Mul),
     //... some other rules 
   }

   if let Some(add_next) = add_next { //if add_next has a value
      push_ops(add_next);
   }
}
```

I need help coming up with an algorithm that can put the operations on the stack in the right order with the correct order of operations (Parenthesis, Exponents, Multiplication, Division, Addition, Subtraction).

I am able to implement comparison methods for operations, so the following is valid

```rs
assert!(Ops::Mul > Ops::Add);
assert!(Ops::Pow > Ops::Div);
```

I am also able to call `tokens.next()` to get to the next token within the loop, and I can call the `match_token` function recursively as needed.

I don't need a solution written in rust. I just need a pseudocode algorithm based on a loop with a match expression for a set of tokens that can convert mathematical expressions to a stack-based AST that respects Order of Operations.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `rust`, but in EBNF style you could use a grammar along the lines of `exp :== term [ ('+' | '-') term];` `term :== factor [ ('*' | '/') factor ];` `factor :== <const> | '(' exp ')';`.

Comment: Two classic solutions: Wikipedia on [Edsger Dijkstra's Shunting Yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) and Douglas Crockford's description of [Vaughn Pratt's Top-Down Operator Precedence algorithm.](http://crockford.com/javascript/tdop/tdop.html). Or save yourself some grief and use a parser generator.

Comment: @rici, Thanks. Those links, especially the Wikipedia are helpful. I am using a PEG parser generator, but it doesn't do operator precedence by itself.